# How can I find & replace a comma with a space when it appears in a certain pattern?

Tags: regex, wildcards

How can use find and replace in Notepad++ to find all instances of the following pattern, and replace the comma with a space?

(I'll write it out, and then show and example.)

2-digit number colon 2-digit number comma 2-digit number backslash 2-digit number

Example:

26:41,06/16

What I want is something like this:

26:41 06/16

Thank you for your time and guidance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Regular Expression search.

Search for: `(\d\d:\d\d),(\d\d/\d\d)`

Replace with `(\1) (\2)`

Comment: Parentheses in the replacement string are not necessary, is not it?
If the whole file has that pattern, it is enough to search for `,` and replace it with a space.
If the file does not have only that pattern, it may be necessary to indicate the beginning and end of the line: `^(\d\d:\d\d),(\d\d/\d\d)$`

Comment: @Marco, I specifically put the parenthesis in the replacement string to show the OP. It still works, and it is easy for someone who doesn't understand regular expressions to understand. I wasn't going to do a whole regular expression tutorial, there are plenty of those. The start and end delimiters don't work if something else is on the same line as the target. This was tested with the current version of Notepad++, and it works.

Comment: Thank you very much, Marco, Ron. I kept digging on it and came up with the following solution as well that seemed to work ok in Notepad++ with RegEx selected:

Find: ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}),([0-9]{2})

Replace: \1 \2